# How passing values ​​to construct function with Actions?

Tags: plugins, php, actions

Must use a **do_action ();** to pass values ​​to my class. How do I do that??

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'someClassy', 'init' ));

class someClassy {

    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null, $path, $qnty) {
           //construct what you see fit here....
    }

    //etc..
}
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded#Parameters hook doesn't take any arguments. What do you mean by "must use a do_action()"? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
class someClass {

    public function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null, $path, $qnty) {
        //construct what you see fit here....
    }

    //etc..
}

// Action listener
add_action(
    'action_name',
    create_function('', "new someClass(implode(',',func_get_args()));"),
    10,
    5 // IMPORTANT, number of arguments your construct function accept
);

// Call the action
$options = "options";
$initialize = "initialize";
$error_messages = "error_messages";
$path = "path";
$qnty = "qnty";
do_action('action_name', $options, $initialize, $error_messages, $path, $qnty);
?>
```

Comment: ERROR: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in...

Comment: @Lollipop just fixed it